# What would be the powershell equivalent of the given curl using cer/pem for authentication?

Tags: powershell, authentication, curl

I have a curl command to a rest service requiring authentication as below:

```
curl -s --key private_key.pem --cert certificate.cer $url
```

Now this command works perfectly giving a valid json back

Now I need to use powershell due to some project requirements. For that I tried using Invoke-RestMethod as below

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Certificate certificate.cer
```

I gives me error as given below:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Certificate'. Cannot convert value ".\certificate.cer" to type 
"System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate". Error: "The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also tried adding the certificate to a certificate store in windows. Now querying the $url gives me an unauthorized response back.

Please help me using the pem and cer files to authenticate the service. No username/password is supplied for any alternate means.

Comment: `$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]::CreateFromCertFile('C:\path\to\certificate.cer'); Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Certificate $cert`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for the snippet, but when I try, I still get the unauthorized response back. Do I need to use the pem file somehow as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I got that to work by converting the certificate to a pfx-certificate using openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out .\certificate.pfx -inkey .\private_key.pem -in .\certificate.cer
```

Then I used the Invoke-RestMethod as below

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath .\certificate.pfx
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Certificate $cert
```

I got a valid JSON response. Thanks for your help.